# Home range - match symbol colour to polygon colour

Tags: qgis, vector

I have a data set for point locations for birds and I am creating maps to show their home range.

I would like to match the symbol colour (for the points) for each bird to the polygon colour that I created using minimum bounding geometry.

At the moment because there are so many birds using a colour ramp doesn't work as there are too many birds so many have too similar of a colour. So I am using a random colour ramp.

I could individually go through and assigned them a colour I know but I was hoping there may be a quicker way like saving the random colour ramp I have for the symbols and then applying it to the polygons.

Comment: For those of us who don't know what a "home range" looks like and who can't imagine how your project (and desired output) looks like: can you add a screenshot?

Comment: It's a bit like having cities for differents civilizations, and the expension of these civilizations ;-)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I assume this for your data:

- Layer1: Bird's observation, with an attribute with the specie name.
- Layer2: Home range, with an attribute with the specie name, the same
  as above.

Set the symbol color for the Layer1.
Use the plugin "color to attribute" on this layer, to have a new attribute, called `symbol_color`.
[image]
Now, in the properties of the Layer2, join the table of Layer1, to match the species names, and add the attribute `symbol_color`.
[image]
Then, In properties-->symbol of the Layer2, set the color of your symbol with this attribut.
[image]
If you decide to change the color of one of your point, just redo the plugin "color to attribut" on the same attribute.
[image]