# Geometry generator with QGIS expression: collect_geometries for overlaying layers, based on attributes

Tags: qgis, symbology, expression, geometry-generator

- I have a point layer "Layer1", with an attribute called `L1_att`.
- I have a surface layer "Layer2", with an attribute called `L2_att`.

In my symbology of Layer1, I have categorized with `L1_att`. I have a point symbol (different color for each value) and also a "geometry generator" with type as surface.

For the geometry generator part, what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
collect_geometries(overlay_intersects('Layer2', 'L2_att'="L1_att",$geometry))
```

This means, I want to collect the polygons that overlay my point layer, but only if their attributes are the same!
And secondly, if a polygon covers 2 points, does it show this feature twice? Cause I want it to be shown only once.

Hope it is clear enough!

EDIT: I try Babel's solution (see below), but it doesn't seem to work:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: new version**

Use this expression:

```
geometry (
    get_feature_by_id (
        'Layer2',
        array_first (
            if (
                L1_att = array_first (overlay_intersects('Layer2', L2_att)),
                overlay_intersects('Layer2', $id),
                ''
))))
```

*Screenshot: point X is inside polygon X and polygon Y, but only polygon X is created with Geoemtry generator, based on the common attribute value `X`:*
[image]

**Old version**

Use this expression:

```
collect_geometries (
    if (
        L1_att = array_first (overlay_intersects('Layer2', L2_att)),
        overlay_intersects('Layer2', $geometry),
        ''
))
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work! I had a screenshot above. I should have only 4 different colors, with same transparentcy. But I have feature that are represented multiple times (red feature at South is present 7x times), and with different colors (big feature on the North should only be red but it's also purple and green)!?!

Comment: OK, so probably I don't understand exactly how your result should look like. Can you add a screenshot that shows what you want to achieve? Or add more information.

Comment: Multiple features: yes, for each point that fulfills the condition, you get a separate feature. If you use Geometry by expression, you can then run `Delete duplicate geometries`.

Comment: I'm trying to find a more "straight forward" solution for the question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412023/home-range-match-symbol-colour-to-polygon-colour

Comment: My problem is if I use "geometry by expression", I have a new layer... but I don't want that.

Comment: The ìf`condition doesn't seem to work... it's collecting all the feature that overlays the corresponding point. For exemple, if my point is "AAA" and a polygone is also "AAA", then it takes ALL the polygones that overlay points with "AAA"... and not only the polygones with "AAA". In the expression overlay_intersects, it is not writen somewhere to do that only on that kind of polygones!!!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand: "it takes ALL the polygones that overlay points with "AAA"... and not only the polygones with "AAA""...?

Comment: In your expression, it's only the conditions that checks if the L1_att and L2_att are the same. Once it is done, it will collect ALL the geometries that overlay the point layer... not only those with L1_att = L2_att. If you test your method, and you check/uncheck your legend, you can see that!

Comment: The reason is because I can have a point with "AAA" value that is in a "AAA" polygone, but also in a "BBB" polygone (overlapping polygones allowed). So the result of the condition is TRUE, cause a AAA-point overlays a AAA-polygones. But as result, it will takes the AAA-polygone AND the BBB-polygone, cause both overlay the AAA-point!

Comment: OK, hope I understood it correctly now: see my edited answer.